# How to set dynamically check boxes disable Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added check boxes dynamically using data table and grid view.
But all the check boxes are disable.  How to enable it?

this is my code

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("UserAcess");         

    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("PageName");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);


    foreach (var item in RoleName)
    {
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(item.RoleName, typeof(bool)); 
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    }



    foreach (var page in pageName)
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["PageName"] = page.PAGE_NAME;

         foreach (var role in RoleName)
        {                  

           dr[role.RoleName] = false; 

        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    gridUserAcess.DataSource = dt;
    gridUserAcess.DataBind();
```

this is my grid view.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridUserAcess" runat="server">


    </asp:GridView>
```

I don't knowhow to set check box property.
Please help me..

Comment: where's the code where you add in the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Find the check boxes inside the grid and then when the check boxes are found use .Enabled property to enabled false.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
 Page.FindControl("yourCheckBoxId").Enabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

what to you mean by "Dynamic" - are the checkboxes in the markup of your GridView or do you create them somewhere else in your code behind.

You can use Eval in your Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="deactivated" runat="server" checked="<%#Eval(Container.DataItem, 'Deactivated')%>"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Otherwise use

```
gridUserAccess.FindControl()
```